# Should be type placed on both sides of declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

With the `type MyType` being

```
export type MyType = 
  {
    ID: string, 
    Name?: string
  };
```

I can go ahead and declare variable `myVar` using three slightly different syntax:

1. With `MyType` next to the variable name:

```
let myVar: MyType = { ID: "abc" };
```

2. With `MyType` after the value:

```
let myVar = { ID: "abc" } as MyType;
```

3. With `MyType` next to the variable name and after the value:

```
let myVar: MyType = { ID: "abc" } as MyType;
```

Would be any difference in the resulting `myVar` variable using any of three methods? What should be a preferred way and why?

Comment: The third option is essentially the same as the second one

Answer (score 1):

Using `: someType` on the left hand side is *type annotation*. It indicates that the only thing assignable to the variable should be something of that type. When you *need* to indicate to TS that a variable should contain a particular type, that should be preferred.

You should avoid `as`, which is *type assertion* - which basically tells the compiler "I'm sure I know what I'm doing, the expression on the left is really of type X even if you can't infer it." This should be avoided when possible, since it reduces the amount of type-checking TypeScript can do in some circumstances.

That said, often, you don't need either of those: that is, having TypeScript infer `myVar` to be of type `{ id: string }` will probably work in most circumstances, especially if you aren't reassigning the variable (best to avoid variable reassignment when possible anyway - it's usually simple enough).

So, consider if you can do just

```
let myVar = { ID: "abc" };
```

without any typing at all. It'll be safe to use for, eg, arguments that expect something of `MyType`, but without any type annotation or assertion (less unnecessary type noise often makes code more readable).

Comment: Small nitpick, but having `let myVar = { ID: "abc" };`, typescript will not infer `myVar` to be type `MyType`, but rather `{ ID: number; }`. Of course that is indeed assignable to `MyType`, but if you add any additional required properties to `MyType` then TypeScript won't complain at you on the declaration (but it will when using the variable somewhere that expects `MyType`). Your answer is correct, just clarifying a minor detail.

Answer (score 0):

In Option 1, you are declaring the variable as of a certain type and assigning it a value.  If the value does not fit the type, it will complain at compile time.  This is the preferred method as you get advanced warning that something might not match up correctly.

In Option 2, you are declaring a typeless variable and kind of casting the values to a certain type. This can be useful at times but also could give you run time errors, depending on usage (YMMV)

Option 3 is not really used as it's redundant, IMHO.